# Send email from web browser

Tags: html, html-email

This question is hard to explain and can be vague. What I am trying to achieve is something similar to the click of a "[reply](http://toronto.en.craigslist.ca/tor/eve/2940846940.html)" button found on Craigslist.

What makes this unique compared to a simple mailto or using an smtp sever is that the user must log in to their email accounts and automatically goes to send email with the send information available or (already given) eg. "joesmith@email.com".

Where do I find information on this? and examples.

Note that I use Visual Studio 2010 language C#

Comment: mailto access microsoft outlook unless there's something I am missing

Comment: I deleted my previous comment after following the link you provided and getting a better idea as to what you're looking for. But for clarity, mailto links access the default email client. Almost all the time, people don't change their default email client, so it is usually Outlook Express/Windows [Live] Mail/MS Outlook. I do think it's *possible* to change your default email client to a webmail client, but I think almost nobody ever does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish something similar to the Craigslist example by creating links with the following URLs:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=<to_address>&su=<subject>
http://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?to=<to_address>&subject=<subject>
http://mail.live.com/mail/EditMessageLight.aspx?n=&to=<to_address>&subject=<subject>
http://webmail.aol.com/Mail/ComposeMessage.aspx?to=<to_address>&subject=<subject>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. May I ask where did you find the resource or info on it?

Comment: Well I kinda stole it from their page, but I have also found the information via a Google search: [here](http://my.opera.com/Rijk/blog/2006/07/11/mailto-to-webmail).

Comment: Wow I am anciently behind. 2006 is a big gap.